# Icefaces and javascript bridge

Tags: javascript, icefaces

I'm facing a problem with **Icefaces** and it's **javascript bridge**.
I don't know what are the changes which made by this bridge after i made a changes in the server-side.

For example: I have a **ice:panelPopup** component in my page with the visible attribute = "**#{bean.customPopUp}**". If i changed the "**bean.customPopUp**" to be "**true**" the popup is displayed correctly, but what i need to know : what happened in the client, in other word, i need to know if the popup is displayed i need to do some client processing using javascript

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you want to know if ICEfaces requires JavaScript, then the answer is definitly Yes. These "partial refreshes" require JavaScript on the Client side to modify the DOM.
Anyway, can you please state more precisely what you need to know about ICEfaces' JavaScript bridge?

Comment: Thank you & sorry for my bad English.
I use ice:panelPopup, i need to know when this popup displayed. I need any flag or hint to tell me that, because i need to do some JS after the popup displayed.
I use Ice.onSendReceive but the it fired before the popup is displayed.
I tried:
Ice.onSendReceive('document:body',
window.setTimeout("detectPopUp()",1000);
});
detectPopUp(): to get the popup using it's ID.
But i think it's not a perfect way & not work everytime.
I tried
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),"detectPopUp()");
in my bean but not worked.
So what to do

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a solution for component level callbacks also. There doesn't appear to be a good solution to this problem. I've resorted to initiating a recursive polling function in Javascript that handles my task after it detects an update to my component. My backing bean starts the poller() and it runs every 500ms until the component update has occurred.

```
var pollingCount = 0;
var previousValue;

function poller() {
    // Kill poller after 30 seconds
    if (pollingCount >= 60) {
        pollingCount = 0;
        return;
    }

    var currentValue = document.getElementById('myInputElement').value;
    if (previousValue != currentValue) {
        previousValue = currentValue;
        pollingCount = 0;
        myFunction();
    }
    else {
        pollingCount++;
        setTimeout('poller()', 500);
    }
}
```

My backing bean:

```
updateDataModel(); // Causes 'myInputElement' component to update

FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(fc, "poller();");
```

I don't like this solution very much, but there don't appear to be any great answers at this time.